# After upgrading to Angular 12 getting Error: NGCC failed

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I was working on Angular 8 project when the time came to upgrade it to Angular 12. Since I come exclusively from React environments, didn't think it would be this much of a hassle until I started. It has been 2 days that I have been following [Angular Upgrade guide](https://update.angular.io/?v=8.2-12.0), but keep getting the following error:

```
⠋ Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'text')
    at NodeObject.getText (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:152697:31)
    at getRequiredModulePath (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\host\umd_host.js:519:99)
    at Object.getImportsOfUmdModule (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\host\umd_host.js:510:23)
    at UmdDependencyHost.extractImports (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\dependencies\umd_dependency_host.js:43:54)
    at UmdDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.recursivelyCollectDependencies (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\dependencies\dependency_host.js:85:32)  
    at UmdDependencyHost.DependencyHostBase.collectDependencies (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\dependencies\dependency_host.js:38:22)
    at DependencyResolver.getEntryPointWithDependencies (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\dependencies\dependency_resolver.js:75:22)
    at EntryPointCollector.walkDirectoryForPackages (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\entry_point_collector.js:47:52)
    at EntryPointCollector.walkDirectoryForPackages (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\entry_point_collector.js:75:103)
    at C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\ngcc\src\entry_point_finder\program_based_entry_point_finder.js:124:100
C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:139
            throw new Error(errorMessage + `NGCC failed${errorMessage ? ', see above' : ''}.`);
            ^

Error: NGCC failed.
    at NgccProcessor.process (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:139:19)
    at <project_name>\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\plugin.js:129:27
    at Hook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:20:1)
    at Hook.CALL_DELEGATE [as _call] (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:14:14)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1043:30)
    at C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1088:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.compile (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:1083:28)
    at C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:200:19
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:18:14)
    at run (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:154:33)
    at C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:149:6
    at Compiler.readRecords (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:920:11)
    at run (C:\<project_name>\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:145:26)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! <project_name>@0.0.0 start: `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the <project_name>@0.0.0 start script.
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "aly",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "12.2.12",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "12.2.12",
    "@angular/animations": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^12.0.0-beta.35",
    "@angular/forms": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^12.2.12",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^3.0.1",
    "@covalent/core": "2.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^8.3.29",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.176",
    "@types/xml2js": "^0.4.9",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "color-string": "^1.6.0",
    "core-js": "^3.19.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "lodash.debounce": "^4.0.8",
    "ng2-dnd": "^5.0.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^8.2.0",
    "ngx-text-equality-validator": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.3.3",
    "npm": "^6.14.15",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.6.7",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "timers": "^0.1.1",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "xml2js": "^0.4.23",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.12",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^12.2.12",
    "@angular/language-service": "^12.2.12",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/node": "^12.20.36",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.7",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "^8.10.2",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "4.3.5",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "^2.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "baseUrl": "./"
  }
}
```

I have checked for out-of-date packages with `npm outdated` and updated all of them. Most of the answers posted here unfortunately did not work for me, such as setting `enableIvy` to true/false and removing node_modules/reinstalling them. Any additional help or advice is appreciated.

Comment: If one of your ng libraries does not support ivy for example it messes up your project. Try upgrading to ng11 or extract until you find the culprit

Comment: Thank you, I did that and found a package that was 4 years old and not used.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did the above suggestion solve your problem? Problem started appearing with Angular 12.2.11. Angular 12.2.10 is working without errors.

Comment: Yes, the problem disappeared. tried all the proposed answers on SO, but none worked. Bottom line is, you probably have incompatible package with the angular version that is being used. I went through each one and uninstalled it until I found the one which was causing the error.

Comment: @misha130 would you post your answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I haven't got an answer. I have the same problem and I can't fix it because I can't find the exact library out of the 50 I have installed. It just sucks and I hate angular. Post your own answer and I'll upvote it.

Comment: I totally did not see your comment - FYI, I don't like it also

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check each dependency to find if any library is not aligned with the latest Ivy changes, which may be causing the error (as [misha130](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2490286/misha130) suggested in the comments).

In my case, the project did not have a lot of dependencies, so it may be easy enough to go through each dependency and uninstall each one until the app starts without errors.

---

If you still have trouble identifying the culprit, another option [from a response on Angular's issue tracker](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/44369#issuecomment-1003098174) is to modify the @angular/compiler-cli source locally to log the the culprit.

For example, if you see in error like:

```
Error: Then-statement inside UMD wrapper is not an expression statement:                                                                          
{                                                                                                                                                 
    var v = factory(require, exports);                                                                                                        
    if (v !== undefined) module.exports = v;                                                                                                  
}                                                                                                                                             
    at extractFactoryCallsFromIfStatement (<YOUR_ANGULAR_REPO>/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/ngcc/src/host/umd_host.js:658:23)


An error occurred during the build:
Error: NGCC failed.
```

Try searching through your project's `node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli` for the function `extractFactoryCallsFromIfStatement` and in that function, log the source file. For example,

```ts
if (!ts.isExpressionStatement(currentNode.thenStatement)) {
  console.log(currentNode.thenStatement.getSourceFile()); // <-- YOUR LOG STATEMENT
  throw new Error('Then-statement inside UMD wrapper is not an expression statement:\n' +
                    currentNode.thenStatement.getText());
}
```

which will log the culprit package that you can update to a version that supports Angular Ivy.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Angular version 13.2.6 and I also had an "NGCC failed" issue, and most of the answers provided here such as, setting enableIvy to true/false and removing node_modules/reinstalling them couldn't help me.

My NGCC error occured after I ran the command `npm i --save-dev @types/node`, which updated some packages in my development environment but also killed my application, probably there was an issue with the alignment of libraries.

> ***Solution***:

To **revert back** the changes, I went online and found this nodejs page:
https://nodejs.dev/learn/update-all-the-nodejs-dependencies-to-their-latest-version

The npm command shown below (from the above link) helped me to revert back to an error-free version of my application:

`npm update --no-save`

After I ran this command, my application was back to it's normal working state.
*I hope this helps someone.*